How to fix this subscript
I wrote this code
$$\left._{X(\Gamma)'}\left\langle \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \vers{n}_1}, v \right\rangle_{X(\Gamma)}\right.$$

Where
\vers{}

is a command
\newcommand{\vers}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}

But the first subscript it's too high compared to the second, I can't lower it despite technically the size of the \left. is the same as the internal one.
Can anyone help me?
The result on the right of the arrow is how I would like it to look (I did it with Paint), the one on the left is how it looks.


I tried using \atop but it comes out badly and the font comes out too small
I also tried with \begin{matrix} but the font becomes too large
I tried using chatGPT but it's useless



Please do you can put a minimal working example where we can see your screenshots after the compilation?

Unrelated, you should avoid $$ for math equations.

@Sebastiano Done

Using \smash to align the subscripts with tensor package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
\[\tensor[_{\smash{X(\Gamma)'}}]{\left\langle\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial\hat{\mathbf{n}}_1},\nu\right\rangle}{_{X(\Gamma)}}
\]
\end{document}


Related:

The \prescript command from the mathtools package gives incorrect alignment

Left and right subscript / superscript


For the last link there is not the use of \smash command.

I didn't know the package for tensors, it is also useful for other courses, thank you very much

In the 2nd my link there are differents manners to have aligned subscripts. However for my humble opinion the answer of @egreg is the best.

Note Edited to fix the baselines

I suggest to employ \DeclarePairedDelimiter (see the manual of mathtools). Attaching a prescript is just a matter to add a suitable phantom.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\vers}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\innerproduct}{\langle}{\rangle}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xinnerproduct}{sommm}{%
  % #3 = inner product
  % #4 = pre subscript
  % #5 = post subscript
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    {\vphantom{\innerproduct*{#3}}}_{#4}{\innerproduct*{#3}}_{#5}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      {\vphantom{\innerproduct[#2]{#3}}}_{#4}{\innerproduct[#2]{#3}}_{#5}%
    }{%
      {}_{#4}\innerproduct{#3}_{#5}%
    }%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\[
\xinnerproduct*{\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \vers{n}_1}, v}{X(\Gamma)'}{X(\Gamma)}
\]

\[
\xinnerproduct{a,b}{X(\Gamma)'}{X(\Gamma)}
\]

\[
\xinnerproduct[\big]{a,b}{X(\Gamma)'}{X(\Gamma)}
\]

\def\test{\rlap{\vrule width 4cm depth 0.1pt height 0pt}}
\[
\xinnerproduct*{\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \vers{n}_1}, v}{\test X(\Gamma)'}{X(\Gamma)}
\]

\[
\xinnerproduct{a,b}{\test X(\Gamma)'}{X(\Gamma)}
\]

\[
\xinnerproduct[\big]{a,b}{\test X(\Gamma)'}{X(\Gamma)}
\]

\end{document}


Using $$ in LaTeX has been deprecated from day one.

But the baselines of the pre- and post-subscripts are not the same.  (Not up to ypur usual precision.)

@barbarabeeton You didn't lose your eagle's eye!
